# Server's Certificate is not trusted In Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I've followed this instructions: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html

On my local machine it worked fine. But when i tried to do the same on live server, certificate still is not trusted. Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Still not trusted by *whom*? A self signed certificate must be added to the trust list *of every site visitor*

Comment: @RemusRusanu I've added certificate to Trusted Root CA. How could i add to the list of "every site visitor" ?

Comment: Obviously can't add to every visitor. This is why you cannot use self signed certs for public, live, sites. This is orthogonal to any platform, browser, http server.

Comment: Buy a server certificate from a valid CA.